# What does -s and [[]] mean in an if condition in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

`if [[ -s log.txt ]];`

What does -s mean? I know -z means zero sized string. I cannot find any documentation on -s.

What does [] or [[]] mean, while writing an `if` condition. I have used `if` without [] or [[]] and it worked fine.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `-s` test returns true if

> [...] if file exists and has a size greater than zero

This is documented in the `bash` manual, and also in the manual for the `test` utility (the test may also be written `if test -s file; then`).

For `[ ... ]` and `[[ ... ]]`, see: [Bash - If Syntax confusion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248164/bash-if-syntax-confusion)

Answer (score 0):

`-s` FILE:-  FILE exists and has a size greater than zero.

The [[ ... ]] part allows to test a condition using operators. Think of it as an if statement. In your example, you're using the `-s` operator, which tests that the referenced file is not empty.