# Bash script to detect empty message string. Getting: too many arguments

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a bash script where I can pipe in output from another application into the below script. But I think I have an incorrect logic for testing if the message is empty or not. If its empty I want it to do nothing, but if it detects the word "error" in the string, it should run another function.

What am I doing wrong in my logic?

I'm getting too many arguments on the 3rd to the last line, most likely due to the message being empty.

```
message=$( cat )

if [ -n "${message// /}" ]; then
  #execute if the the variable is not empty and contains non space characters
  message="\`\`\` ${message} \`\`\`"
else
  #execute if the variable is empty or contains only spaces
  message=""
fi

sendX() {
.....
}

if  [ -z "$message" ]; then
        echo "Please pipe a message to me!"
else
        sendX
fi

sendAlert() {
......
}

checkword="error"

echo $message

if [ $message =~ $checkword ]; then  <---- Error: too many arguments
 sendY
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting a "too many arguments" error since `[ ... ]` does not understand the `=~` operator (used in `bash` for regular expression matching). Since `[ ... ]` does not understand the operator, it is treated as a string.  You then have `[ ... ]` with three strings inside it, and they don't fulfil the semantic requirements for a proper test, which is why `bash` errors out at this point.

In `bash`, you would use `=~` inside of `[[ ... ]]`.

However, what I assume you'd like to do in that test is to see whether `$message` contains `$checkword` as a substring.  This could also be done with

```
[[ "$message" == *"$checkword"* ]] && sendY
```

or with `case ... esac`:

```
case $message in
    *"$checkword"*) sendY
esac
```

This way you don't have to worry about `$checkword` containing characters that may be special in regular expressions.

You also need to double quote `$message` in `echo $message`, or you may get unexpected output if `$message` contains filename globbing characters like `*`.

Related:

- [Bash - If Syntax confusion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248164)
- [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803) (because it would be better to use `printf '%s\n' "$message"` than `echo "$message"` for user-supplied data)
- https://www.shellcheck.net/ (which would have picked up these issues and possibly others, like missing a proper `#!`-line)

---

You could also use this instead of the first operation in the script:

````
case $message in
    *[!\ ]*) # contains non-space
        message='``` '"$message"' ```' ;;
    *)       # contains nothing or only spaces
        message=
esac
````

Using `case ... esac` in both places would make your script (at least the bits that you have shown) portable to any `sh`-like shell.